# dynamic jquery listener

Tags: jquery, ajax, listener

How can i create a dynamic listener using jquery to run different ajax tasks?

For example, `stackoverflow` have a delete link for each comment without `onlick` in it, so i'm guessing that they created a class listener, but how does it know which id to use in the ajax url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML could contain something like:

```
<span class="delete-link" data-id="15">Delete comment 15</span>
```

Then, with jQuery, you could add callbacks on that class:

```
$('.delete-link').click(function() {
    var comment_id = $(this).data('id');
    /* send ajax request for that comment ID */
});
```

Comment: but their link doesn't contain `data-id` attribute.. how?

Comment: +1 jQuery imports data attributes for you, so you could also use `$(this).data('id')` to get the same value.

Comment: @tamir, the delete links from StackOverflow contain IDs like `delete-post-6403452`. You can extract the post ID from there. For comments, there are `tr`s with `comment-7507772`, then all the delete actions inside the `tr` can extract the ID from there.

Comment: @lonesomeday, that's nice, didn't know about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is done by the `id` property on the `tr` ancestor of the comment.

The HTML looks something like this:

```
<tr id="comment-7507745" class="comment">
    <td class="comment-actions">
        <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="comment-score">
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="comment-up comment-up-off" title="this is a great comment">upvote</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <!-- and a whole bunch more -->
    </td>
</tr>
```

So the code might be implemented with code a bit like this:

```
$(document).delegate('a.comment-up', 'click', function(event) {
    var commentId = $(this).closest('tr.comment').attr('id').substr(8);

    // do something with the comment id
});
```

So the data is stored as an attribute, and DOM traversal is used to find the relevant element where the data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

with the bind method

```
$('a', '#container').bind('click',function(e){
    /* stuff */
});
```

(and unbind, for removing)

Or if you are asynchronously appending new links you can use the live function

```
$('a', '#container').live('click',function(e){
    /* stuff */
});
```

(opposite of live, is die( event ) )

Clicking on a link, child of #container will call the anonymous function within the arguments of bind/live, You can then check which link was clicked by checking for its index, or class, or anything - and run different code.